# Decoding a variable-length JSON array into a Rust array

Tags: json, serialization, rust

I'm trying to decode this data:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": "10"
    }
  ]
}
```

Into a struct.The code is:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::json;

#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct Man {
    name: String,
    age: i32,
}

#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct Men {
    ok:      bool,
    people: [Man; 16],
}

...

let json: Men = json::decode(&data).unwrap();

...
```

The problem is that when the length of the array in `Men` doesn't match the length of corresponding field in JSON exactly, this error happens:

```
thread '<main>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()`
on an `Err` value: ApplicationError("wrong array length")',
../src/libcore/result.rs:738
```

Any ideas on how to deal with this?
General code style advice is also welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having an array that is only partially filled doesn't really make sense. Arrays statically know exactly how much space to allocate, but you have to fill that space with *something* in avoid some security issues with uninitialized data. They have no concept of "unused" spots.

The easiest fix is to use a [`Vec`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html):

```
#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct Men {
    ok:     bool,
    people: Vec<Man>,
}
```

A `Vec` represents a *resizable* contiguous amount of data. It knows how much space is allocated *and* how many of those allocations are valid, and will never let you access the invalid items.

Answer (score 4):

Well, either you really have only lists of men with length 1, in that case you could change the type to `people: [Man; 1]`. Or you actually have variable length at run-time, in which case you'd be better off picking a dynamically sized vector like `people: Vec<Man>`.

As a hint: `serde` and `serde_json` might be better choices as dependencies, since `rustc-serialize` was only extracted from the compiler, so that it would not have to end up in `std` permanently.