# Parse a json with arrays with serde

Tags: rust, serde

I would like to parse a json with an array inside:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Device {
    pub path: String,
    pub start_sector: Option<u64>,
    pub end_sector: Option<u64>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Config {
    pub hostname: String,
    pub devices: [Option<Device>],
}
```

Anyhow I cannot manage to deserialize an object with an array inside, as I get: `error: cannot deserialize a dynamically sized struct`. You can find my attempts [here](https://github.com/yottaStore/yottafs/blob/feat/config/packages/config/src/config.rs).

How can I parse variable length arrays in serde?

Answer (score -1):

I just add to search slightly different terms, here's the answer: [Decoding a variable-length JSON array into a Rust array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298262/decoding-a-variable-length-json-array-into-a-rust-array)

I had to use a Vec instead of an array/slice.